# Remove all characters after a comma with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove all characters after the "," in a string using jQuery, by targeting the class of the element. Other solutions I found were using javascript, targeting the string itself instead of the class.

My code is:

```
<td class="priceinfo">€779,34&nbsp;</td>
```

How do I remove the characters after "," in the text of the td element?

Comment: `$('.priceinfo').text((i, t) => t.replace(/,.*/, ''));`

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `text()` method to achieve this. By providing a function as the argument to the method call that action will be performed on every element in the collection.

```js
$('.priceinfo').text(function(i, t) {
  return t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td class="priceinfo">€779,34&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="priceinfo">€2,34&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="priceinfo">€1,290,34&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

The JS code can be made even more succinct if you use an ES6 arrow function, but note this is not supported in IE:

```js
$('.priceinfo').text((i, t) => t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf(',')));
```

Comment: Just to know Why passing two parameters ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh: first one is for index and second for current value.thats how syntax  of callback function works in jquery.

Comment: Those parameters are defined by jQuery. `i` is the index of the element in the matched set and `t` is it's current text value. See http://api.jquery.com/text for more info

Comment: Thanks , understood guys

Answer (score 3):

```
use below code

$('.priceinfo').html().split(",")[0]


below is the working fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fwyjp52/1/

Answer (score 1):

This way to do it remove **all** characters after the first comma:

```
$(function(){
    $('.priceinfo').each(function(){
      text = $(this).text();
      textSplit = text.split(',');
      $(this).text(textSplit[0]);
  });
});
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3mdjpcu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or **you don't have to use a tank to hammer a nail** and just use *jQuery-free*™ solution:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.priceinfo'), function (el) {
    var h = el.innerHTML;
    el.innerHTML = h.substr(0, h.indexOf(','));
});
```